# cypress - click iframe element while the body of the iframe change after few seconds

Tags: iframe, cypress

I have a problem when using `cy.getIframeBody().find('#some-button')` that the #some-button element is not yet available, because the iframe is still loading, but the body element is not empty so the .find() is triggered.

This is the custom command to get the iframe body

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getIframeBody', ()=> {
    return cy.get('iframe.cy-external-link-container')
        .its('0.contentDocument.body')
        .should('not.empty')
        .then(cy.wrap)
});
```

How I can do it without using `cy.wait()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add random timeouts and `.should()` assertions, but if they work at all the test is likely to be flaky.

The key is to repeat the query of the body element (this line)

```js
.its('0.contentDocument.body')
```

until the button shows up.

So not

```js
.its('0.contentDocument.body')
.should('not.empty')
```

but something like

```js
.its('0.contentDocument.body')
.should('have.child', '#some-button')  // force a retry on body query
```

`.should()` with callback will do this

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getIframeBodyWithSelector', (waitForSelector) => {
  return cy.get('iframe.cy-external-link-container')
    .its('0.contentDocument.body')
    .should(body => {
      expect(Cypress.$(body).has(waitForSelector).length).gt(0)
    })
    .then(cy.wrap)
})

it('finds some button', () => {
  cy.getIframeBodyWithSelector('#some-button')
    .find('#some-button')                      // passes
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an timeout and also add `should('be.visible')`. should assertion will make sure that till the timeout value is reached it rerties and make sure that the iframe is loaded successfully.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getIframeBody', () => {
  return cy
    .get('iframe.cy-external-link-container', {timeout: 7000})
    .should('be.visible')
    .its('0.contentDocument.body')
    .should('not.empty')
    .then(cy.wrap)
})
```

Comment: my problem is that when the iframe open we have temporary body that soon will change to the body that I want to catch. if I use this code I will get the first body and then it will not found the button that I need

Comment: Please add your html to the question.

Comment: This is the most robust solution so far, works like charm in C10. Thanks for sharing!